# when i open a url using inappbrowser it doesn't open

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

When i try to open a url in android using inappbrowser, the url does not open a shows a blank screen with the url on the top. But when i try to open the same url in chrome it is opening fine and also on ios device it is working fine.
Issue only comes when opening in android inappbrowser.
Is it some javscript issue or something else, i m not able to figure it out.
this is the code which opens the url:

> const browser =
>   this.iab.create('loginDetails.serverURL','_blank','location=yes,toolbar=yes');

Comment: [Connect your mobile app to your computer](https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/debugging-an-ionic-android-app-using-chrome-dev-tools-6e139b79e8d2). It should help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this..

```
String link=URL_LINK;
if (!link.startsWith("http://") && !link.startsWith("https://")){
      link = "http://" + link;
   }
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(link); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
   context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: my link starts with "https://" and is a valid link as it is getting opened in browser and ios inappbrowser. So i think this is not the issue in my case